# Cant seem to scale image down to fit parent screen size in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I have a react native project that display a bunch of short films. I am currently trying to add short film thumbnails into a `Flatlist`. I want to add a thumbnail, director, genre, ... and more. My main issue is with the image scaling.

The original image in pretty big and so I just want to scale the image down so that the width of the image is 100% of the parent component. I want the heigh of the image to automatically scale down as well to keep the original aspect ratio.

I have tried 4 or 5 different ways to scale it down but non of it is working.

The best results I got was using the following:

```
<Image style={styles.featuredThumbnail} source={require("../../assets/images/augustsky.jpeg")}/>

featuredThumbnail: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
```

the issue is that the image is still taking up the original height. I dont want to hard code the height because then with other thumbnails it distorts the images

Here is what it is looking like right now.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?